# A lot of js.map file not found after upgrade to Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, requirejs, magento2.4.3

I just upgraded my magento version to 2.4.3-p1, and after i login to the admin site there are a lot of js.map file not found in the console log message:

[image]

How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Are all of them related to PageBuilder? In the screenshot yes, but, I wonder if there are more, some not related to PageBuilder? Does it affect the admin functionality? Or you just see the errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in CSS path

**like : pub/static/version323334/**

then run this query in my SQL

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
after that clear the config cache



bin/magento cache:clean config
```

**IF the Above simple does not work then please try the below::**

**SOLUTION # 1 (IF YOU WANT TO EDIT XML FILE)**

Now we are going to clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2. Go to following paths and delete everything:

```
ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
```

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up `di.xml` in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Now last step, also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

For Those who are on **Magento 2.2.x**

> **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`**
>
> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
> Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Answer (score -1):

Once again run all below command and checking. It's Working.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml sudo rm -rf pub/static/_cache sudo rm -rf var/cache sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/generation sudo rm -rf var/generated sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf var/log sudo rm -rf var/report sudo rm -rf generated/code/ sudo rm -rf generated/metadata/

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```